# Jquery Each for Parent TD's

Tags: jquery, html

I am having HTML as below:-

```
<table id='mytable'>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>--------Parent td
   <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </td>
  <td>--------Parent td
   <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need to find only parent td's using jquery each function.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where are you stuck? This is quite a basic application of a CSS selector.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i am writing this in content editor webpart might be because of that it is not working.

Comment: @Lalji Anwsers works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use immediate child selector here:

```
$('#mytable > tbody > tr > td')
```

Comment: your answer works fine, don't know why i got down votes?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [immediate child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) here:

```
$('#mytable > tbody > tr > td').each(function() {
     //do something
});
```

Comment: i think what op needs is `$('#mytable > tr > td').each(function() {});`

Comment: @Banana: yup...can say that. the idea was using correct selector.

Comment: it is not working jquery link i am using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: @ShariqueAnsari link the jquery in the page's head above all other scripts and make sure you dont link multiple jquery versions

Comment: @Banana ya that i did but i am writing this script in content Editor webpart browser i am using IE10.

Comment: is your code reachable?? try alerting for element count using `$('#mytable > tr > td').length`.also make sure the code is written when dom is ready.

Comment: i have written another function like this $("#mytable tbody tr").each(function(){ }) is works fine, but not $('#mytable > tr > td').each(function() {});

Comment: @ShariqueAnsari: the html you shared did not had tbody in it. how did the solution worked for you??